# Manually set cookie value to disable Anti-forgery Token?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I still don't understand how the Anti-forgery Token works in MVC.
From the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-attacks).

**Anti-Forgery Tokens**

To help prevent CSRF attacks, ASP.NET MVC uses anti-forgery tokens, also called request verification tokens.

1. The client requests an HTML page that contains a form.
2. The server includes two tokens in the response. One token is sent as a cookie. The other is placed in a hidden form field. The tokens are generated randomly so that an adversary cannot guess the values.
3. When the client submits the form, it must send both tokens back to the server. The client sends the cookie token as a cookie, and it sends the form token inside the form data. (A browser client automatically does this when the user submits the form.)
4. If a request does not include both tokens, the server disallows the request.

Here is an example of an HTML form with a hidden form token:

```
<form action="/Home/Test" method="post">
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden"   
       value="6fGBtLZmVBZ59oUad1Fr33BuPxANKY9q3Srr5y[...]" />    
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

My question is that since we can find the hidden token value easily by looking the source code (F12 in any browser). Then can we manually set the cookie by going to the Developer Tools (Ctrl-Shift-J or Tools -> Developer Tools) -> Console and the you can enter javascript command:

document.cookie="keyofcookie=valueofcookie"?

Then we cam manually set the tokens same therefore to disable Anti Forgery technology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That cookie is HttpOnly and it cannot be set from javascript since all latest browsers implement HttpOnly. Also, both cookie token and form token contain different base 64 encrypted information. Decryption will be server side stuff.

Moreso, These tokens are not compared for equality. They complement each other for data. Also, you did not read the complete article. MVC has its own methods to validate token as well..

Check if the link below helps.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/793384/ASP-NET-Anti-Forgery-Tokens-internals

Comment: I am not strong on cookie. So how do you know that cookie is HttpOnly?

Comment: Like you, i also read that on internet. But now, since you asked, here is the link for actual microsoft file source code. Here is the MS link about open source. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/henrikn/2012/08/17/getting-started-with-asp-net-web-stack-source-on-codeplex/  .  Check the HttpOnly true. http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/9a83b63f3f889e3f2c979274fe3e8f7610e06b98#src/System.Web.WebPages/Helpers/AntiXsrf/AntiForgeryTokenStore.cs

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-attacks) says:

> Anti-forgery tokens work because the malicious page cannot read the
>   user's tokens, due to same-origin policies. ([Same-origin policies](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy)
>   prevent documents hosted on two different sites from accessing each
>   other's content. So in the earlier example, the malicious page can
>   send requests to example.com, but it cannot read the response.)

That means, copying the cookie value and using it to any different location will not work because of the said policy.

Comment: I still don't understand the sentence `the malicious page cannot read the user's tokens,`. Do you mean  we can't read the cookie by the script `var x = document.cookie;`?